# What happens beyond file-copying when npm does an install?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am developing a Javascript system where the main component uses another as an installed package, and I am working on both components. I have it set up so that the directory for this package in node_modules is a soft link to the directory where the package files are generated. But I find that, when I update the package files, I still have to increment the version number in the package's package.json file and run `npm update`. If I don't do that the old version of the package is still used.

To be clear about the setup, the entry for the package in the main project's package.json file looks like this:

> ```
> "myPackage": "C:/path/to/packageOutputDir",
> ```

(The package has generated code and packageOutputDir has the files that are needed for the library.) And the directory entry in the main system's node_modules looks like this:

> lrwxrwxrwx  1 myId Domain Users 69 Apr 16 00:11 myPackage -> /cygdrive/c/path/to/packageOutputDir/

So they both point to the same place.

So, I am wondering:

1. Where does npm keep the current version number so it can tell when I've incremented it? It's clearly not comparing the local myPackage/package.json to the remote packageOutputDir/package.json because they're the same file.
2. Similarly, where does it keep the old code that is still running until I increment the version number and run npm update again?

What I wanted to do was to make it so that I could test my code modifications without incrementing the version number and running `npm update` again. But instead, the updated code was not used until I did just that. Answers of the form "you shouldn't be doing what you're doing, do X instead" are fine, but I do really want to understand what's going on with npm.